# MongoDB Insertion faliure Report

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

Is it possible to know Document Insertion failure in MongoDB. I am using C# to connect to MongoDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable the "safe mode" on the operation level. safe=True in Python. Check with the C# drivers docs for the related functionality in C#.